# NextJs - Displaying server side errors in production

Tags: next.js, error-handling

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling#handling-server-errors

Above doc link tells

> If an error is thrown inside a Server Component, Next.js will forward an Error object (stripped of sensitive error information in production) to the nearest error.js file as the error prop. During production, the Error object forwarded to the client only
> includes a generic message and digest property.
> This is a security precaution to avoid leaking potentially sensitive details included in the error to the client.
> The message property contains a generic message about the error and the digest property contains an automatically generated hash of the error that can be used to match the corresponding error in server-side logs.
> During development, the Error object forwarded to the client will be serialized and include the message of the original error for easier debugging.

In my app, i have controlled errors and i want to display those messages to user for some clarity, is there a way I configure nextjs to pass me actual error message to be displayed on error page and skip stripping of error message?